# Does Istio Gateway Mode Mutual verify the client certificates by building a chain?

Tags: x509certificate, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

I have set my IngressGateway mode to mutual and provided my SSL cert, private key and list of trusted intermediate issuers and Roots as CA Certs.

I am wondering how does Istio actually verify the identity of the client cert, does it build the chain at the gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway) you can verify if the secret was successfully created and then pushed to the gateway:

> - Verify that the secrets are successfully created in the  `istio-system`  namespace:
>
>   ```
>   kubectl -n istio-system get secrets
>   ```
>
> `httpbin-credential`  and  `helloworld-credential`  should show in the secrets list.
>
> - Check the logs to verify that the ingress gateway agent has pushed the key/certificate pair to the ingress gateway.
>
>   ```
>   kubectl logs -n istio-system "$(kubectl get pod -l istio=ingressgateway \
>   -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')"
>   ```
>
> The log should show that the  `httpbin-credential`  secret was added. If using mutual TLS, then the  `httpbin-credential-cacert`  secret should also appear. Verify the log shows that the gateway agent receives SDS requests from the ingress gateway, that the resource’s name is  `httpbin-credential`, and that the ingress gateway obtained the key/certificate pair. If using mutual TLS, the log should show key/certificate was sent to the ingress gateway, that the gateway agent received the SDS request with the  `httpbin-credential-cacert`  resource name, and that the ingress gateway obtained the root certificate.

The example is based on this [guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway).